# Why timestamp columns in Spark dataframe changed during write to Hive table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to read Oracle table using JDBC and insert data into Hive table, but all timestamp column's values was changed (-6 hour). Why it changes timestamp?

I've tried to use "spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC" to spark config but it didn't help

```scala
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder
      .config(sparkConf)
      .config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

val dataDF = spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
    .option("url", s"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//${configuration("dwh_address")}")
    .option("user", configuration("dwh_username"))
    .option("password", configuration("dwh_password"))
    .option("dbtable", s"(${select * from source_table})")
    .option("fetchSize", configuration("fetch_size"))
    .load()

dataDF.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").insertInto("target_table")
```

This is how source row in table looks like:

```
ID        DATE

1509808,   2019-11-04 00:00:00.0
```

This is how Hive table looks like after INSERT:

```
ID        DATE

1509808,   2019-11-03 18:00:00.0
```

I don't have any idea why all TIMESTAMP columns has changed to - 6 HOURS and hope that somebody already faced with such issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your TIMESTAMP column in Spark is a DateType. Setting the configuration "spark.sql.session.timeZone" to "UTC" only has some effects when you format the timestamp as string, but the date will be saved in a Date object, where the timezone doesn't matter.

If you want to access it again as UTC, you can get the timestamp and cast it or use "spark.sql.session.timeZone" to change the default timestamp time zone.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , please check if your source timestamp in which time zone.Accordingly you can override the timezone using below and it will convert time back to your original timestamp

If your source timestamp is in MST then use below :

--conf spark.sql.session.timeZone=MST

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the timezone of the server where Hive is installed(Hadoop cluster) ? Hive takes the timezone that's set at the JVM level, which in turn takes system configured timezone.